# csv not recognizing null on last line

Tags: apex, csv

The question is in regards to importing a csv into apex. The easiest way to explain this is to reference my debug log. In this log this is the test collection of 2 objects, account and registration, the last field "`Days_to_Complete__c"` is my concern, this is the last column in the csv:

```
DEBUG|
(cpeRegistration:[acc=Account:{LastName=Test, FirstName=CPE, UFID__c=1123998}, 
                  reg=Registration__c:{Days_to_Complete__c=2
    }], 
 cpeRegistration:[acc=Account:{LastName=Test2, FirstName=CPE2}, 
                  reg=Registration__c:{Days_to_Complete__c=}])
```

`"Days_to_Complete__c"` should have not been created at all. Why was it? How do I stop the field from being created? For all of the other inputvalues, this if statement will stop the field from being added to the object:

```
if(inputvalues[20]!=null && inputvalues[20]!='' && inputvalues[20]!='""')
  {r.Days_to_Complete__c = inputvalues[20];}
```

Switching the columns around in the csv does not matter, consistently, the last column does not null/blank out properly from if statement.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: 1) show the CSV source; 2) show the debug output for the last line of CSV (all entries in `inputValues`; 3) `!String.isBlank(inputValues[20])` is the proper method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. It was finding a carriage return on the last column in the csv, by setting up an escape for the carriage return it ignored the carriage return and solved my issue. Like this:

> && inputvalues[20] != '\r'

Just to follow through with crop1645: 1. The csv was not making a difference, I moved the columns around, and received the same result no matter what the last column was. 2. I did find the carriage return in the debug log though, and once I added the escape it worked. 3. Thank you for pointing out the isBlank method, I had tried that though in my original iterations trying to solve this issue, no dice, it was ultimately the escape from /r that I needed.